# ORDER BY dentro de un GROUP BY con tres tablas

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, group-by, relaciones, modelorelacional

Buen, de verdad que necesito de su ayuda.
Tengo 3 tablas: Empleado, Tienda y Empleado_Tienda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla "Empleado_tienda" es una tabla pivote, la cual uso porque llevo un **historial del reasignaciones** de los empleados, es decir, 1 empleado puede trabajar en la tienda **X** por un periodo de 6 meses, luego es reasignado a la tienda **Y** por 4 meses y asi sucesivamente. Para poder saber cual es la tienda actual de un empleado, en la tabla pivote hay una columna FechCambio, la fecha más reciente me indica la tienda actual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es listar todos los empleados ACTUALES que pertenecen a una Tienda, es decir ordenar por (fechCambio, Desc) y tomar el ultimo asi para todos los empleados. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He tratado de hacerlo con GROUP_CONCAT, pero creo que deberia ser con un ORDER BY y luego GROUP BY.

```
SELECT R.FK_idEmpleado, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(R.fechCambio ORDER BY R.fechCambio SEPARATOR '|') fechaCambio,
    GROUP_CONCAT(T.nombre SEPARATOR '|') NombreTienda,
    GROUP_CONCAT(R.FK_Tienda ORDER BY R.FK_idTienda SEPARATOR '|') idTienda

FROM Empleado_Tienda R INNER JOIN Tienda T
ON R.FK_idTienda = T.idTienda
GROUP BY R.FK_idEmpleado
ORDER BY R.FK_idEmpleado, R.fechCambio;
```

Alguna sugerencia, o comentario, quizás el diseño de las tablas deberia cambiarlo, gracias de antemano

Comment: Por favor, pásanos la estructura de la base de datos con algún registro de muestra (phpMyAdmin, Exportar) para hacer las pruebas, y el resultado que esperas obtener para esos datos de ejemplo

Comment: hola @DavidJP, he agregado a la pregunta el resultado esperado, ojala me puedas aunque sea dar indicios de lo que puedo hacer

Comment: Gracias @Edu27, el dataset con los CREATE TABLE y los INSERT es necesario para replicar tu base de datos, utilizar en la consulta tus nombres de campo y contrastar el resultado

Comment: @DavidJP, aqui esta la estructura y el dataset :  https://we.tl/t-AWg7LRqOWj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ésta es una posible solución a lo que estás buscando:

```
SELECT idEmpleado,apPaterno,fechCambio,nombreTienda
  FROM (
    SELECT FK_idEmpleado,
      MAX(fechCambio) fechCambio
      FROM empleado_tienda
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 JOIN empleado_tienda
  USING(FK_idEmpleado,fechCambio)
  JOIN empleado ON FK_idEmpleado=idEmpleado
  JOIN tienda ON FK_idTienda=idTienda;
```

Para este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE `empleado` (
  `idEmpleado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `apPaterno` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apMaterno` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
CREATE TABLE `empleado_tienda` (
  `idReasignaciones` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fechCambio` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `FK_idEmpleado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FK_idTienda` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
CREATE TABLE `tienda` (
  `idTienda` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombreTienda` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `empleado` (`idEmpleado`, `apPaterno`, `apMaterno`) VALUES
(1, 'Garcia', 'Torres'),
(2, 'Herrera', 'Lopez'),
(3, 'Ullo', 'Paredes'),
(4, 'Muñoz', 'Sandoval');
INSERT INTO `empleado_tienda` (`idReasignaciones`, 
  `fechCambio`, `FK_idEmpleado`, `FK_idTienda`) VALUES
(1, '2018-01-01 00:00:00', 1, 2),
(2, '2019-01-01 00:00:00', 1, 3),
(3, '2019-04-01 00:00:00', 1, 1),
(4, '2018-06-01 00:00:00', 2, 3),
(5, '2019-07-01 00:00:00', 2, 2);
INSERT INTO `tienda` (`idTienda`, `nombreTienda`, `direccion`) VALUES
(1, 'Tienda Principal', 'Avenida 1'),
(2, 'Tienda Secundaria', 'Avenida 2'),
(3, 'Tienda plaza', 'Avenda 3');
```

Obtendrás este resultado:

> ```
> 1 Garcia  01/04/2019 0:00:00  Tienda Principal
> 2 Herrera 01/07/2019 0:00:00  Tienda Secundaria
> ```

No es exactamente el tuyo porque había algunas infracciones de clave ajena. Probablemente habrías eliminado alguna tienda.

Y también había un empleado que se iba a dos tiendas diferentes en la misma fecha. Igual sería recomendable definir una clave única `UNIQUE(FK_idEmpleado,fechCambio)` para evitar situaciones similares.

**Explicación**

La parte más complicada es la de obtener `c1`, la subconsulta que identifica la fecha del último cambio de cada empleado. Con estos dos datos, ya se puede combinar con la tabla `empleado_tienda` por empleado y fecha para obtener esa última tienda a la que ha sido asignado.

Con estos datos de empleado y tienda ya se puede combinar con empleados y tiendas con sus `id` para obtener todos los datos necesarios.

Después ya puedes ordenar por tienda o por empleado, lo que prefieras.

Espero que fuera lo que estabas buscando. Cualquier cuestión, déjamela en los comentarios y ampliaré la respuesta.

Comment: Sos lo maximo!!!!, no sabes cuantos dias estuve intentando, de verdad muchas gracias! ese GROUP BY 1 no sabia que se podia usar asi.

Comment: Es una forma abreviada que permite MySQL, funciona también con el `ORDER BY` [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 1):

Posiblemente lo que buscas se resuelva con la combinación de [MAX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column.html) y `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT E.idPersonal, E.apPaterno, E.nombres, MAX(R.fechCambio) AS Fecha, R.motivo, T.nombre
FROM Empleado_Tienda R 
INNER JOIN Empleado E ON E.idPersonal=R.FK_idEmpleado
INNER JOIN Tienda T ON T.idTienda=R.FK_idTienda
GROUP BY E.idPersonal ORDER BY E.apPaterno ASC
```

La parte de `ORDER BY E.apPaterno ASC` no es necesaria para que funcione, es solo para el orden alfabético de los apellidos.

Comment: ¿No deberías agrupar por el resto de columnas en el select menos la de max?